# Kivy, changing source picture of canvas from python file

Tags: python, image, canvas, kivy, kivy-language

I am making a weather app and need to be able to change the canvas picture of a FloatLayout from the .py file, due to a substantial amount of code needed to choose the image. I chose the FloatLayout to house the image due to size_hint and pos_hint(don't want to hassle with manually changing params when app is adjusted).

The real question is how I can transfer a string between the .kv and .py file to the canvas->rectangle->source and have it update to display the image that is in the directory.

Here is the .kv file snippet. The underlined part is where the string should be.
[image]

I am trying to use a method in the class that holds all the code to update the image.

Any ideas on how I can do it?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing that `source` line with:

```
source: app.image_source
```

And in your `App`, add a line:

```
image_source = StringProperty('path/to/initial/image')
```

Then you should be able to just update the `image_source` property to change the image.

Comment: I had to use root instead of app but it does the same thing. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Set `source: root.some_property_name` and then in your method set `self.some_property_name` to the filepath you want.

Also add `some_property_name = StringProperty()` in the class.